# Expected response code 220 but got code "500" when sending mail in Laravel 5.4 in local environment

Tags: laravel, smtp, local, swiftmailer

I'm migrating a Laravel 5.0 app to 5.4 and am trying to test the mail in my local environment. I've always used [Anitix SMTP Imposter](https://ssfd.codeplex.com/) for this. Here's what my mail configuration looks like in my .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=127.0.0.1
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPT=null
```

This has always worked in all previous versions of Laravel (4, 4.2, 5.0), but suddenly with 5.4 I'm getting the following error:

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
>   Expected response code 220 but got code "500", with message "500 Command not recognized
>   "

I've tried disabling Avast, using alternative programs like [Papercut](https://papercut.codeplex.com/), playing with the config by using SSL or TLS, but I can't figure out what's causing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

Late answer, but I came here myself running into the same issue.

MailHog does not support TLS encryption. Adding `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null` to my `.env` file fixed my issue.

Comment: Better late than never! Still relevant in 2022. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First try: **php artisan config:cache** and restart your local server, perhaps Laravel use the old mail data.

For development purpose https://mailtrap.io/ provides you with all the settings that needs to be added in .env file. Eg:

```
Host:   mailtrap.io
Port:   25 or 465 or 2525
Username:   cb1d1475bc6cce
Password:   7a330479c15f99
Auth:   PLAIN, LOGIN and CRAM-MD5
TLS:    Optional
```

Otherwise for implementation purpose you can get the smtp credentials to be added in .env file from the mail (like gmail n all)

After addition make sure to restart the server

Comment: Thanks, the config:cache command didn't change anything. I set it up with mailtrap.io, and it works that way, but I'd still like to know why it isn't working with my local apps like it was in previous versions of Laravel.

Comment: this is just an alternative, but not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://mailtrap.io/
it will provide you all necessary details for you to check mail functions in your local machine including username,password,port,host,etc.

**if still have same issue issue,
use these details in `config/mail.php` file in your project instead of using .env file.**

```
return array(
        "driver" => "smtp",
        "host" => "mailtrap.io",
        "port" => 2525,
        "username" => "mailtrap.io_your_username",
        "password" => "mailtrap.io_your_password",
        "sendmail" => "/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs",
        "pretend" => false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is work for me.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I am use a mailhog docker container.

```
mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
    ports:
      - "1025:1025" // smtp 
      - "8025:8025" // web
```